# Why typescript infers value type of variable defined with "let" as "any" if it was initialized with "null" value?

Tags: typescript

```
let value = null; // why infered as "any"?
```

Why typescript infers value type of variable defined with "let" as "any" if it was initialized with "null" value? For what purpose is this done?

Comment: What other type do you propose the variable should have?

Comment: Variable defined with "const" infers as "null" type.

Comment: OK, but if you declare it with `let` - indicating you may want to reassign it with a different value later - why should the type be `null`, preventing you from giving it any other value?

Comment: Try to apply your statement to other primitive types (string or number). And you will see why I asked this question

Comment: Well no, if I write `let value = 5;` then the inferred type is `value: number`, and there are lots of other values which I can reassign the variable with. If I write `let value = null;` and it infers `null` as the type, there is no other value I can reassign the variable with. That's my point. A variable (not a `const`) of type `null` is useless, it might as well be `const`, and then you might as well just use literal `null` values in place of the variable. So my question is: why would you want the type to be inferred as `null`? What would be the advantage of that?

Comment: The advantage is that there will be less confusion and less "implicit any" cases

Comment: @AlexanderPankin you either want the type to always be `null`, thus you should use `const`, or you want it to be changeable to something else, thus `null` would be wrong. `let foo:null = null;` is always wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From the [TypeScript 2.0 documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html)

> The type checker previously considered null and undefined assignable
> to anything. Effectively, null and undefined were valid values of
> every type and it wasn’t possible to specifically exclude them (and
> therefore not possible to detect erroneous use of them).